# Google Shortcut Open invited window

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In the official documentation of Google Chrome in the section of [Shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) does not appear the functionality to open a new guest window, there is only the combination of (CTRL + Shift + N) but it opens an incognito window...

is it possible to open a invited window with a key combination?

Comment: with guest you mean another user profile? CTRL+N opens a new window, while CTRL+SHIFT+N opens an incognito window as you noticed. could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok = CTRL+N opens a new window, Ok= CTRL+SHIFT+N opens an incognito window....  But I am talking about opening a guest window, that is, right where it is indicated in this screentshot https://i.imgur.com/jUBPeoU.png

Comment: check this [How to Enable Guest Brows­ing Mode With Short­cut in Google Chrome](https://www.guidingtech.com/25669/guest-browsing-shortcut-chrome)

Comment: It is an article from 2013, and there is no option "Enable new profile management system", it seems that you cannot do what I require.

Comment: currently not on my work Windows computer but on my Mac this works line 1: `#!/bin/bash` line2: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --guest` in a bash script, so you could create a desktop shortcut which will start Chrome with the guest setting and assign the desktop shortcut a keyboard shortcut. I was not able to find any information that a keyboard shortcut is integrated into Chrome for this.

Comment: I understand, so Win10 is not possible my request in a simple way

Comment: Doesn't have to do anything with Windows. The keyboard shortcuts are defined within the app. And creating a Windows Desktop Shortcut and assigning a keyboard shortcut I would declare as a simple way. A more complicated would be to install a third party app like AutoHotKey and script all the shortcuts you need - BTW I am a big fan of AHK ;)